# if-else for multiple conditions dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know how to right properly the following idea:
I have a dataframe that has two columns, and many many rows.
I want to create a new column based on the data in these two columns, such that if there's 1 in one of them the value will be 1, otherwise 0.
Something like that:

```
if (df['col1']==1 | df['col2']==1):
   df['newCol']=1
else:
   df['newCol']=0
```

I tried to use .loc function in different ways but i get different errors, so either I'm not using it correctly, or this is not the right solution...

Would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this post: [pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `np.where` or `np.select`

```
df['newCol'] = np.where((df['col1']==1 | df['col2']==1), 1, 0)
```

OR

```
df['newCol'] = np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], [choice1, choice2, choice3], default=def_value)
```

When a particular condition is `true` replace with the corresponding choice(`np.select`).

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this using `.loc`,

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] == 1 | df['col2']==1) ,'newCol'] = 1
df['newCol'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

incase if you want newcol as string use,

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] == 1 | df['col2']==1) ,'newCol'] = '1'
df['newCol'].fillna('0',inplace=True)
```

or

```
df['newCol']=df['newCol'].astype(str)
```

Comment: thanks. but this is only for case where value is boolean.
What would i do if i want the new column to be string?

Comment: can you show me a sample data? where the above one doesn't work

Comment: here's an example that won't compile:
```
data['status'] = np.where((not(pd.isnull(le_data['mode'])))|pd.isnull(le_data['status']), 'not_active', 'active')
```